# Can VBA be used to get the creation/modified date of attachment itself, not the email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba

I would like to see the creation and modified dates of an Outlook attachment using VBA. No such property seems to exist.

```
Public myAhmt As Attachment
Public crDt As date
crDt = myAhmt.CreationDate 'no such property exists
```

For `mailitems` the `.sentOn` property is nice, but I want the date of the attachment not the email. After saving to my hard drive with `.SaveAsfile`, the creation date is indeed accessible (either by manual inspection in Windows Explorer, or using a `fileSystemObject` in VBA) ... But it would be nice to see it before saving already.

There seems to be something like `.propertyaccessor.getproperties(...)`, but I don't know how to use it, or if it will work.

Is there a way to see the creation and modified dates of an Outlook attachment using VBA?

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything either. Does it have to be VBA? I found this AddIn which captures the date you are looking for - [OutlookAttachView v2.47 - View/Extract/Save Outlook Attachments](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_attachment.html)

Comment: Hi thanks, the Nirsoft App would indeed probably be the one I'd use in the absence of VBA. I want to do some tweaks though (renaming, comparing etc) that I prefer to do via code... Just my own pref! Regards

Comment: When you inspect the creation date using Windows Explorer, doesn't it just show the date and time that you saved the attachment from the email? That seems to be the case for me (Outlook 2010 / Windows 7)

Comment: hi yes, but I want to see this date in Outlook VBA before I detach it using VBA (not by hand)....